# execute javascript method after completing code behind method?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I want execute below callback() method after completion of `document.getElementById('btnDownload').click();` method . Now `callback()`executing immediatly. I want wait "Click()" process done then Execute  `callback();` method.

```
function LoadPopup() {
        //  find the popup behavior
        this._popup = $find('mdlPopup');
        // show the popup
        this._popup.show();

        // synchronously run the server side validation ...
        document.getElementById('btnDownload').click();
       callback();         
    }

 function callback() {
        this._popup = $find('mdlPopup');
        //  hide the popup
        this._popup.hide();
        alert("hi");
```

}

Comment: Rewrite your question.  It's not clear at all what you are asking.

Comment: Are you saying that clicking the button activates some server-side logic, and you don't want the callback() method to execute until it's completed?

Comment: Put the callback inside the AJAX success?

Comment: Syntactic, you are right. I am want execute callback() method after completion .click() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But I will give you a example.

For example, you wan to load a page by clicking on a image then after the page load is complete you want to do something you can something like this

```
$('#buttonid').click(function() {
    //this is the callback function of click event
    //if you want some other callback functions then you need something like this
    $("#somediv").load("page.php", function() {
       //callback function code of .load event
       alert('page loaded');
       });
 });
```

What you are asking is to have a callback function inside the default callback function of click event and a bit impossible from my point of view.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've wildly misunderstood the question, this code will make a request to the page that the link leads to, and when the server has returned the response, executes the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnDownload").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      complete: function(xhr, status) {
        callback();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

I may have wildly misunderstood the question...